# Torch - Load saved model and test a single image for classification

Tags: lua, torch

I'm using code from this repository - [gtsrb](https://github.com/preethamsp/tutorial.gtsrb.torch). I have successfully trained the model with over 95% accuracy. However, I'm not sure how to get a single image tested against an already trained model. I have a trained model saved under `saved_models` directory with the name `egg_net_best.h5`.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
input = image.load(path_to_single_image, 3)
model = torch.load('saved_models/vgg_net_best.h5')
output = model:forward(input)
```

This gives me an output but I don't understand the format. It gives me a 9x11 tensor which looks like this

```
-3.1302 -2.7557 -3.6514 -5.1083 -0.4339 -3.6722 -6.7406 -4.1163 -3.2751 -3.0417 -2.4740
-4.6895 -4.5554 -1.1019 -4.1954 -1.0187 -3.2853 -4.7917 -5.1205 -2.6658  -2.3842 -2.8388
-3.2914 -2.7516 -2.1224 -4.6314 -0.7596 -3.0647 -5.5749 -3.9037 -3.4147 -2.9719 -1.9181
-3.7006 -3.0220 -2.3870 -5.2183 -0.5729 -3.1286 -6.1271 -4.4617 -3.6552 -3.1698 -1.9662
-2.4560 -2.7865 -2.0729 -2.7589 -2.4757 -2.6934 -1.3172 -2.5542 -3.0839 -3.2817 -2.4930
-3.5149 -3.2504 -2.4154 -4.9333 -0.6504 -3.3700 -5.3838 -4.4408 -2.5233 -2.3310 -2.4659
-3.5452 -4.1833 -3.3995 -2.3409 -2.9932 -2.7852 -0.5702 -3.0504 -2.8158 -3.8218 -3.9147
-3.1225 -2.7842 -2.9371 -4.6879 -0.6197 -3.1266 -5.6755 -4.0995 -3.7424 -3.1942 -1.8000
-2.9004 -2.4582 -2.5652 -4.6114 -0.6186 -3.3890 -4.1276 -3.7448 -3.1053 -3.0396 -2.6929
```

Questions:

1. Is the approach to test a single image against a trained model right ?
2. Why am I seeing a 9x11 Tensor while it should be 1x11 ?

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

PS: This question [SO- training single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315851/testing-a-single-image-with-torch7-model) is not what Im looking for.

Edit 1:

As per suggestion I did the following but the results are just the same.

> Lua 5.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
>
> path = '/Users/pamio/Workspace/practices/torch/test_model/test/00010/IMG_2522.JPG'
>
> input = image.load(path, 3)
>
> model = torch.load('saved_models/vgg_net_best.h5')
>
> model:evaluate()
>
> output = model:forward(input):exp()
>
> =output

Columns 1 to 10

```
   0.0257  0.0621  0.0027  0.0169  0.0132  0.0530  0.6320  0.0798  0.0022  0.0138 0.0985
   0.1033  0.0838  0.0705  0.0609  0.1639  0.0678  0.1156  0.0971  0.0653  0.1042 0.0676
   0.0101  0.0262  0.0010  0.0053  0.0014  0.0312  0.8307  0.0349  0.0002  0.0050 0.0541
   0.0666  0.1656  0.0054  0.0337  0.0112  0.0537  0.3638  0.1694  0.0062  0.0134 0.1111
   0.0589  0.0663  0.0298  0.0148  0.1565  0.0976  0.2328  0.1159  0.0324  0.0978 0.0972
   0.0511  0.0786  0.0153  0.0549  0.0341  0.1121  0.3010  0.1052  0.0314  0.0994 0.1169
   0.0619  0.0777  0.0395  0.0521  0.0358  0.1125  0.3184  0.0785  0.0150  0.0588 0.1498
   0.0153  0.0319  0.0009  0.0080  0.0015  0.0386  0.7779  0.0449  0.0003  0.0079 0.0726
   0.0123  0.0285  0.0059  0.0062  0.0048  0.0455  0.7893  0.0269  0.0013  0.0177 0.0615

   [torch.DoubleTensor of size 9x11]
```

Edit2:

```
> print(model)
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (1) -> (2) -> output]
    (1): nn.Sequential {
      [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> (11) -> (12) -> (13) -> (14) -> (15) -> (16) -> (17) -> (18) -> (19) -> (20) -> (21) -> output]
    (1): nn.SpatialConvolution(3 -> 32, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (2): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (32)
    (3): nn.ReLU
    (4): nn.SpatialConvolution(32 -> 32, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (5): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (32)
    (6): nn.ReLU
    (7): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2,2)
    (8): nn.SpatialConvolution(32 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (9): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (64)
    (10): nn.ReLU
    (11): nn.SpatialConvolution(64 -> 64, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (12): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (64)
    (13): nn.ReLU
    (14): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2,2)
    (15): nn.SpatialConvolution(64 -> 128, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (16): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (128)
    (17): nn.ReLU
    (18): nn.SpatialConvolution(128 -> 128, 3x3, 1,1, 1,1)
    (19): nn.SpatialBatchNormalization (4D) (128)
    (20): nn.ReLU
    (21): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2,2)
  }
 (2): nn.Sequential {
    [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> output]
    (1): nn.View(4608)
    (2): nn.Linear(4608 -> 512)
    (3): nn.ReLU
    (4): nn.BatchNormalization (2D) (512)
    (5): nn.Dropout(0.500000)
    (6): nn.Linear(512 -> 11)
    (7): nn.LogSoftMax
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the image you are loading doesn't have the correct size. The network was trained with images of 3x48x48 while you are feeding them with a bigger height and width making the model internal layers mess up and treating them as batches instead of a single image.

The following code is working for me:

```
model:evaluate();

-- We assume that the image has a wrong size, place here your image loading code
img = torch.Tensor(3, 200, 200)
-- First we scale it to 3x48x48
img = image.scale(img, 48, 48, 'bilinear')
-- Then to avoid errors with the batchnorm layer we make it 4D 
-- (batchNorm expects a 4D tensor)
image = image:reshape(1, 3, 48, 48)
-- Feed the image to the network, add the :exp() if we want to retrieve the probs.
pred = model:forward(img):exp()


-- output
Columns 1 to 10
0.01 *
9.4125  9.0546  8.9142  9.0716  9.0065  9.0865  9.4289  8.7353  9.2937  9.2811

Columns 11 to 11
0.01 *
8.7152
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1x11]
```

Comment: True but thats not the case. BTW, Is my approach of testing a single image against a trained model correct ?

Comment: I also have asked this question on gitter but haven't received any response yet.

Comment: @PamioSolanky Yes, the approach looks correct. Maybe you should also add `model:evaluate()` before the `:forward()` useful for the layers like `dropout()` or `batchNormalization()` that have a different behaviour during training and evaluation. Also, as I mentioned in the answer, as the model in the repository has a `LogSoftMax()` layer at the end you need to add `:exp()` to your outputs to get the probabilities, if you just want to get the best prediction `:sort()` the array. In case you want me to help you solving it paste the `print model` output! Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! will do that. I'm running the model with your inputs and see how it performs. Thanks.

Comment: `model:evaluate()` doesn't do anything as the output is the same.

Comment: Can you paste the `print model` output in your question?

Comment: The model architecture seems correct, what I do not understand is why this output. It seems like it is treating the image as a batch of size 9, therefore returning that matrix 9x11 with the log-probabilities for each of the 9 inputs. The way you are loading the image seems fine as well. Try to reshape it to be a 4D matrix `image = image:reshape(1,3,height,width)`. Also, did you check that the image dimmensions (channels, height and width) are the same as the ones you have used for training? if not maybe you have to apply `image.scale(src, width, height, [mode])`

Comment: For testing purposes, I'm using the same image that was trained already :) So there's no question of image being different or image being of different dimensions. I'll try to reshape it and check again but in my opinion that won't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138205/discussion-between-pamio-solanky-and-manuel-lagunas).

Comment: I'm running through an issue. I have images with object in the centre and some background. Lets say class A has many images with grey background and the object in the image is white. Class B has many images with white background and the object in the image is grey. Now when I test a new image which is class A (grey background) it results with higher probability of it belonging to class B. Why does it happen ?